# Can I enable a unlimited amount of custom themes, besides just the few basic themes: Default, Light, Dark, and HighContrast? (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

The title explains most of it. But say for example in my apps Settings menu I allow the user to select like 20+ different color themes. How do I go about implementing such a feature when Windows 10 only allows me to customize a set number of themes like the Default, Light, Dark, and HighContrast themes? The FrameworkElement.RequestedTheme property does not give many options to work with plain and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What APPEARS to work for me is first creating all of the themes I desire and placing them in their very own ResourceDictionary.xaml file. Once this is done and I wish to switch between themes, I simply create a new ResourceDictionary object and then set its Source property to the theme I wish to load.

Now the x:Key value that you must use EXCLUSIVELY for this approach when adding your custom themes to the ThemeDictionary is the Default key value, and not the Light or Dark key values. They will introduce limitations.

So after loading your custom theme into the newly created ResourceDictionary you must first remove the ResourceDictionary that has "Default" as its associated key from the TheemeDictionary. This is because you obviously can't have multiple objects in a dictionary that share the same key.

Next you add the new ResourceDictionary to the ThemeDictionary in place of the ThemeDictionary you just removed. Give it the exact same "Default" key.

Last, do this:

```
if (this.RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Light)
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
else
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
```

Here you are toggling between the light and dark themes to force a property change (I guess the RequestedTheme property requires a value that is different than its current value to trigger a property changed event). But since you do not have a light or dark theme within the ThemeDictionary, the system will default back to the Default Theme Dictionary that you have in place.

And remember that you cannot change the RequestedTheme value for the root App class, or you will get a runtime error. A nice trick is to simply change the RequestedTheme property for the rootFrame Frame, since your entire UI will be constructed within that frame anyway.

If someone knows of a more sophisticated/appropriate approach to this, PLEASE let us know!

Comment: I think you are on the right way. There are some code shows on the following page which could be your reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/fluent-xaml-theme-editor